# Autoloading rails controllers outside app/controllers folder

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Is there a way how to properly load controllers outside of `app/controllers` folder?
Background - the situation is that we have multiple clients and we didn't want to fork and create client-specific rails apps, therefore, we have only one app and we control business logic via services. Version of the app is determined via `ENV` variables.

We have defined that `app/controllers` folder will only be used for shared logic and we have created folders for each client inside `app/clients/[CLIENT]/` that will be used for client-specific needs - services, concerns, configs, controllers, even specific routes will go here.

From this `app/clients/[CLIENT]/controllers` we would like to additionally load client-specific routes and controllers. An exemplary controller inside the client folder may look like this.

```
module Clients
  module ClientA
    module Controllers
     module Api
       module V1
        class RentalsController < ApplicationController; end
       end
     end
    end
  end
end
```

Is there a way how to properly load this?
I tried doing the following in the `application.rb`

```
config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/app/clients/ENV['CLIENT']/**/**)
```

How do you even mount this controller then? I tried the following but didn't work.

```
resources :rentals, controller: 'clients/ClientA/controllers/api/v1/rentals' do
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use snake_case for the folders -- `client_a` instead of `ClientA`

And then:

```
config.autoload_paths <<
  Rails.root.join(
    'app',
    'clients',
    ENV['CLIENT'].underscore,
    'controllers',
    '**'
  )
```

Comment: Good answer! For the routing, maybe just use a wildcard.
`resources :rentals, controller: 'clients/*client/controllers/api/v1/rentals' do`
https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#route-globbing-and-wildcard-segments

Comment: Sadly the routing doesn't really work for some reason. `ArgumentError: 'client/client_a/controllers/api/v1/rentals' is not a supported controller name. This can lead to potential routing problems. See https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#specifying-a-controller-to-use`

Comment: @GeorgeMorris `clients/` not `client/`